# Increase in Minor GC Pause time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We are facing a strange issue related to minor GC. One of our application which is in production since last 18 months started having higher minor gc pauses times recently. Historically our minor GC pauses were around 30-50 msec, however now they are around 110 msec to 400 msec. There has not been any changes in heap configurations but good number of code changes has gone in.

The application is a Rest web service running on tomcat hosted on a cloud with 8 cpu virtual machines and 24 GB RAM and talking to cassandra. We tried to recreate the issue for debugging the same in a lower environment by running a performance test but not able to do so. There is a single rest service which is invoked with similar workload with 98% of the time however 2% of the workload is bit different. We are not able to load test those 2% of the calls due to data issues.

When we run the load we see that almost same amount of heap is reclaimed or promoted as in normal scenario (load is 8-10 times of production when we run the load test) but minor gc pauses are <50 msec always. (we did run the same load on a production VM as its a read operation)

With Performance test requests(High load):

```
2015-09-15T10:16:51.617+0000: 300001.062: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922537K->174564K(1922560K)] 2146305K->432640K(4019712K), 0.0604696 secs] [Times: user=0.44 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2015-09-15T10:16:54.033+0000: 300003.478: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922383K->174567K(1922560K)] 2180459K->469257K(4019712K), 0.0493751 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
2015-09-15T10:16:56.468+0000: 300005.912: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922535K->174570K(1922560K)] 2217225K->504099K(4019712K), 0.0437478 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
2015-09-15T10:16:58.696+0000: 300008.140: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922538K->174576K(1922560K)] 2252067K->541818K(4019712K), 0.0407501 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:00.887+0000: 300010.331: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922544K->174573K(1922560K)] 2289786K->577682K(4019712K), 0.0468752 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:03.142+0000: 300012.586: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922541K->174581K(1922560K)] 2325650K->617970K(4019712K), 0.0424797 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:05.394+0000: 300014.838: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922549K->174587K(1922560K)] 2365938K->659487K(4019712K), 0.0425134 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:07.661+0000: 300017.106: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922555K->174566K(1922560K)] 2407455K->694256K(4019712K), 0.0389039 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:09.951+0000: 300019.395: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922534K->174577K(1922560K)] 2442224K->726822K(4019712K), 0.0385114 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2015-09-15T10:17:12.302+0000: 300021.746: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922545K->174591K(1922560K)] 2474790K->762111K(4019712K), 0.0400951 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

But at much lesser production load for the same JVM on the same machine, minor GC pauses are quite high:

```
015-09-15T05:36:27.428+0000: 283176.872: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1844205K->125665K(1922560K)] 1991878K->273338K(4019712K), 0.1087286 secs] [Times: user=0.61 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
2015-09-15T05:39:05.945+0000: 283335.390: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1873633K->157526K(1922560K)] 2021306K->305200K(4019712K), 0.1099762 secs] [Times: user=0.58 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
2015-09-15T05:41:43.686+0000: 283493.131: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1905494K->174576K(1922560K)] 2053168K->337666K(4019712K), 0.1249486 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs]
2015-09-15T05:45:06.059+0000: 283695.503: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922544K->174560K(1922560K)] 2085634K->371522K(4019712K), 0.1434632 secs] [Times: user=0.95 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs]
2015-09-15T05:48:08.511+0000: 283877.955: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922528K->174576K(1922560K)] 2119490K->404319K(4019712K), 0.1145014 secs] [Times: user=0.76 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
2015-09-15T05:50:49.150+0000: 284038.594: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922544K->174571K(1922560K)] 2152287K->436331K(4019712K), 0.1178926 secs] [Times: user=0.68 sys=0.00, real=0.12 secs]
2015-09-15T05:54:18.962+0000: 284248.407: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922539K->174560K(1922560K)] 2184299K->467992K(4019712K), 0.0975615 secs] [Times: user=0.63 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
2015-09-15T05:57:45.177+0000: 284454.621: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922240K->174577K(1922560K)] 2215672K->501369K(4019712K), 0.1108669 secs] [Times: user=0.75 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
2015-09-15T06:00:55.609+0000: 284645.053: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922545K->174584K(1922560K)] 2249337K->534084K(4019712K), 0.0970370 secs] [Times: user=0.65 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
2015-09-15T06:03:32.692+0000: 284802.137: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922552K->174582K(1922560K)] 2282052K->569585K(4019712K), 0.1109909 secs] [Times: user=0.80 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
2015-09-15T06:06:14.975+0000: 284964.420: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1922550K->174586K(1922560K)] 2317553K->599629K(4019712K), 0.0967938 secs] [Times: user=0.41 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
```

Now if minor GC pause time consists of Card Scanning, Stack Scanning, Old Generation Scanning and Copy time, which all should be kind of similar if not identical in above scenario, how come GC pauses times are so different? Or am I Missing something very basic here?

```
JVM Version Info:
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Heap parameters are:

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:GCLogFileSize=10485760
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:InitialHeapSize=4G
-XX:MaxHeapSize=4G
-Xmn2G
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=25
-XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

Comment: You might want to try running the logs through Censum: http://www.jclarity.com/censum/

Comment: Censum is recommending -Xmx393M -XX:NewSize=24M for heap. I think that will be too low.

Comment: GC Logs can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yplfctnm8t7ule/perftestgc.log.1.current.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You're using the parallel collector, which has [throughput as its primary goal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html). So it is not surprising that it may make different tradeoffs to reach its throughput goals under different workloads.

If want it to try to keep pauses low you have to specify a [pause time goal.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#parallel_collector_ergonomics)

This is explicitly spelled out in the official documentation:

> by default, there is no maximum pause time goal.

So I find it surprising that you tried all those GC parameters but didn't even try the ones provided in the first few paragraphs.

If you were [cargo-culting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) the parameters from somewhere else I highly recommend that you do not do that without first referring to the documentation to understand their purpose.

---

Edit: Looking more closely at the options you're using, you're pinning the survitor ratio and disabling the adaptive size policy, which prevents the GC from adjusting the new gen to meet pause time goals.

And under different workloads (test vs. production) the age distribution of objects will differ and thus the amount of live objects that need to be marked and copied from the nursery and the from-space.

Together this results in different pause times.

Instead you probably should just specify high level goals and let the heuristics adapt to the changing workloads.

Comment: We did extensive testing before going live for most of the parameters including pause time goals.The problem we are facing is that for the same JVM we had upto 50 msec of pauses (for one and half years) but now those are more than 110 msec. Is there a way to find what made jvm to make different tradeoff?

Comment: I added XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 but it has no impact whatsoever.

Comment: I actually have tried that. Just specified max and min heap and removed everything else like new gen size, survivor ratio and then specified pause time target. still pauses are higher around 100 to 250 msec. My problem is with same tuning parameters it was average 50 msec. Now they are high. I am not sure if we can log the breakdown of young gc pause time somehow and then target specific area.

Comment: do you mean it fails to meet the pause time goals? If so also remove the min heap size, that allows the jvm to start with a smaller young generation. Alternatively you can explicitly specify a smaller young generation since that size is derived from the initial heap size by default

Comment: Yes, it didn't meet the pause time goals. We decided upon the sizes based on load tests initially (simulating our holiday peaks) and hence sized the generations and max and min heap sizes.

Comment: We had a cloud upgrade 2 months back which made changes related to NUMA and cpu pinnings for VMs, We also have cpu frequency auto scaling at our hypervisors but limited tests I have ran so far doesn't indicate issue because of them. Still continuing investigations on that end.

Comment: If you intend to set all settings manually you might also want to tweak the `InitialTenuringThreshold`/`MaxTenuringThreshold ` as that's normally adjusted by `+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` (you should see it in the log output when it's enabled)